# Create array batch based on similar array key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an batch of similar array's based on first key of array.

Here is the input array

```
$headers          = array(
    0 => 'order_number',
    1 => 'product_sku',
);

$input_array = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000706',
    1 => 'S503053'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000706',
    1 => 'S516135'
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000703',
    1 => 'S526587'
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000703',
    1 => 'S526587'
  ),
);
```

I am trying to create an seperate array if it has same order id like if two array has same order id = "311000000706"
then desired output will be

```
$desired_output = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000706',
    1 => 'S503053'
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '311000000706',
    1 => 'S516135'
  ));
```

Here is what i have tried

```
$prev_order_id_s = null;
    $similar_order_ids = array();
      foreach ($input_array as $key => $level):
        if ($level['0'] == $prev_order_id_s) {
            $similar_order_ids[][] = $level;
        }
        $prev_order_id_s = $level['0'];
    endforeach;
```

but i am not getting desired output, i need some advice on this.
can you please advice some logic on this ?

Here is the compiler with above code - paiza.io/projects/fB-8CfiEuTX1cJXnXAZS3g

Comment: Hello, please let me know if any confusion in question or if i can improve code

Comment: Here is the compiler with above code - https://paiza.io/projects/fB-8CfiEuTX1cJXnXAZS3g

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Hello. I am trying to get the desired output mentioned in the question the answeron this question is working but it has static '311000000706'. so its not useful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of maintaining variables for previous order IDs, I would rather suggest you to take advantage of order ID as an associative key and keep adding rows to it whenever you find a matching order ID. In the end, you could [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on the collected data to remove order IDs as keys.

```
<?php

$set = [];
foreach($input_array as $row){
    $set[$row[0]][] = $row;
}

$result = array_values($set);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use foreach to filter your array. You can use the array_filter function in PHP. Let's assume you want to check the first element of each array (means the zero index) and your desired value for this key is '311000000706'. It transaltes to PHP like this:

```
$desired_output= array_filter($input_array, function ($value) {
             return $value[0] === '311000000706';
        });
```

Comment: Hello, this "311000000706" will be dynamic based on the array

Comment: @newtophp Then you can pass whatever value you want to check. In question, you wanted all arrays with a specific value in zero index, so you have to pass the desired value. If the output you showed in question is not what you want then complete your question with more examples

Comment: can you please post an answer how can i generate two seperate array with your answer ?
i am editing your answer to show how i am trying.